# What's the "UnsafeOptInUsageError"?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

I'm using Google MLKit for barcode scanner. When I use `imageProxy.image`, IDE shows a warning;

"`This declaration is opt-in and its usage should be marked with  '@androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage' or '@OptIn(markerClass = androidx.camera.core.ExperimentalGetImage.class)'`"

And it forces to use `@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")` annotation. I don't know what is it and couldn't find any resource(even official resource) about that. So why should this annotation be used?

Answer (score 2):

This waring is from [CameraX library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ExperimentalGetImage) rather ML Kit and you can suppress it by annotating the caller method with @ExperimentalGetImage like [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/VisionProcessorBase.java#L213).